# Pl/Sql Approach to write complex procedure Best Practices

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am relatively new to Pl Sql and have to write a procedure which does following, It has got 6-7 different queries which are as follows :

Select manager, count(*) bank from abc ..........

select manager , count(*) retail from abc .......

Now each count is for a different department , while manager may be same . So problem is that I am looking for a best approach which helps me to store
the data in separate table which has following structure:

Manager : Count Bank  : Count Retail : Count xyz ...........

How do I make sure using Pl sql that each manager has right count for all the columns(bank/retai/xyz)  , the first thing is how to store multiple different query result and process it . I think we can use cursor but I need to research on it , also this procedure should be high performance .
Please suggest.

Thanks
XslGuy

Comment: Looks to me like a school homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily achievable with conditional sums. Hopefully the below will give you enough of an idea of what you need to do:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 1 dept, 10 val from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 1 dept, 20 val from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 2 dept, 30 val from dual union all
                     select 4 id, 3 dept, 40 val from dual union all
                     select 5 id, 1 dept, 50 val from dual union all
                     select 6 id, 3 dept, 60 val from dual union all
                     select 7 id, 2 dept, 70 val from dual union all
                     select 8 id, 4 dept, 80 val from dual)
-- end of creating a subquery that contains some sample data. See sql below:
select sum(case when dept = 1 then val end) dept_1_total,
       sum(case when dept = 2 then val end) dept_2_total,
       sum(case when dept = 3 then val end) dept_3_total
from   sample_data
where  dept in (1, 2, 3);

DEPT_1_TOTAL DEPT_2_TOTAL DEPT_3_TOTAL
------------ ------------ ------------
          80          100          100
```

Comment: ... or looping through a regular cursor with a regular `group by dept`.

Comment: @nop77svk Whilst a standard group by query would give the totals, it would give them as rows, and not columns. Since the OP wanted to insert into a table where the different dept counts are stored as separate columns, then a group by query would need additional work to pivot the results into the correct format. Why bother when you can just do the conditional sums and get the results in the format directly?

Comment: It would be better suited to the OP I think if you grouped by `id`.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Grouping by id in this instance would be meaningless, since it's "unique". This isn't meant to be a complete solution - it's meant to give the OP an idea of how to do the conditional aggregation. Presumably the OP understands that if they need to group by a particular column, they would need to add in a `group by` clause, or if they're calculating the results for a single manager, that they'd just add the `where manager = ...` predicate onto the query.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't look closely -- I thought at 1st glance that `id` was supposed to be the manager ID -- following the OP's requirements.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I didn't hand the OP the full solution because a) they didn't provide the full table and data structure, and b) they'll learn more if they can figure out how to apply the conditional aggregation into their own situation - especially if this does happen to be a homework question! Obviously, more help is available if they get stuck and provide more info *{;-)

Comment: I this answers till some extent to what I am looking for . -- Thanks

Comment: Good luck *{:-) Obviously, if you're going to be inserting rows for multiple managers, you'd first of all write the select statement using group by manager_id with all the conditional case statements, and then you could just turn that into an `insert into ... as select ...` or `merge` statement. No need for procedural (aka looping round a cursor) here, by the sounds of it.